# Disable JQuery barrating rating star plugin hover and click effect

Tags: jquery, ajax, css

I am using Barrating jquery plugin that allow to rate any post and save rating into database.

What i want is if any post already has rating in database just do not allow to hover and select any of star. just display what we got from database. e.g if post has rating of 4 it should just display 4 stars.

You can see my example link below.

http://dev.fingertips-solutions.com/clients/test/

Here is my code snippet. you can view all other code and links through view source.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('.rating').barrating({
                theme: 'fontawesome-stars',
                onSelect: function(value, text, event) {

                    // Get element id by data-id attribute
                    var el = this;
                    var el_id = el.$elem.data('id');

                    // rating was selected by a user
                    if (typeof(event) !== 'undefined') {

                        var split_id = el_id.split("_");

                        var postid = split_id[1];  // postid

                        // AJAX Request
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'rating_ajax.php',
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {postid:postid,rating:value},
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(data){
                                // Update average
                                var average = data['averageRating'];
                                $('#avgrating_'+postid).text(average);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        </script>
```

and this set value

```
<!-- Set rating -->
                            <script type='text/javascript'>
                            $(document).ready(function(){
                                $('#rating_<?php echo $postid; ?>').barrating('set',<?php echo $rating; ?>);
                            });

                            </script>
```

Comment: And if you add option `readonly = true` in config under theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In config have to set these options

```
$('.rating').barrating({
    theme: 'fontawesome-stars',
    hoverState: false,
    readonly: true,
});
```

Comment: I am using star rating plugin but the attributes are the same for that also